# Power BI - stick 2 filters tables

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbuilder, powerbi-custom-visuals

I have dashboard with many visualizations. I want to be able to make one of the visualizations global - when some data from it is selected to remain forever for all other fields unless you unselect it. Here is the example. The main dashboard:

[image]

I want to be able to check something from these table at top and when it filters to remain for all other fields even if I click them. Currently it is working in this way - I choose something from "Resource" table, it filters all other table but when I choose something from other tables it removes "Resource" filter. How can I make it STICK no matter other fields are clicked. Somehow I managed to make "StartTime" to work as expected but I don't remember how. Look at "Project Description" has "StartTime" set as filter:

[image]

I want the same to be for "Resource".

Comment: You are talking about filter are basically Table visual, right?

Comment: You can use the edit interaction so filtering will not affect that table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your issue and presentation correct, you are using Table Visual for filtering purpose and here lies the issue for your case.

Visuals are interactive between each other. This means selecting value in one visual **refresh/filter** data in other visuals. For example, if you select a row in visual A, it will filter data in visual B for the selected value. And now when you select a row in visual B, it will also refresh/filter data in visual A, which is a vice versa action actually. To get rid of this, you can manage the **Interaction** between visuals from the **Format** tab on the top ribbon. This is basically **solution 1** for you.

**Solution 2** and the best option for you is to use **Filter** visual in place of table visual. That case, all selected value in different filter will take impact on data together which is your requirement I guess.